# Get SQL Statement from Category Error in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: sql, azure-log-analytics

I am new to Log Analytics and while I can find that there are SQL errors happening and can count them, group them etc. I can't see in the documentation how to get at the SQL statement causing them.

Currently I have the below and was expecting to extend and project but the columns *_s are all empty.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where Category == "Errors" and error_number_d  == 241
```

What would I need to do from to get at the troublesome SQL?

Many thanks all.

Comment: do you mean get the detailed sql statement like `select * from mytable`?

Comment: that's the one.  just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable diagnostics for that. Refer [AZURE SQL DB AND LOG ANALYTICS BETTER TOGETHER](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-db-and-log-analytics-better-together-part-1/ba-p/794833) for details. SQL statements can be found in `statement_s` column. For example:

```
//Detailed errors
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(15d)  //Last 15 days
| where Category =~ "SQLSecurityAuditEvents"
| where succeeded_s == "false"
| where additional_information_s contains "8134" //Looking for specift error. Ex Div by zero
| extend additional_information_xml=parse_xml(additional_information_s)
| extend failure_reason=additional_information_xml.batch_information.failure_reason
| project    
    ResourceGroup,
    LogicalServerName_s,
    database_name_s,
    session_id_d,
    action_name_s,
    client_ip_s,
    application_name_s,
    failure_reason,
    statement_s,
    additional_information_s
```

[image]

You can also add [Azure SQL Analytics (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql) to your Log Analytics workspace for that. Once you [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql#configuration), the monitoring dashboard is shown.
[image: Screenshot that shows the monitoring dashboard.]

Selecting any of the tiles, opens a drill-down report into the specific perspective. Once the perspective is selected, the drill-down report is opened.